# getting value from another function and class c++

Tags: c++

Sorry guys I'm new to C++ and I have this silly question to ask. how to I retrieve the value of civIndex from LocationData computeCivIndex function to PointTwoD class. does the GET function help in this situation?

LocationData.h

```
class LocationData
{
  private:
    string sunType;
    int noOfEarthLikePlanets, noOfEarthLikeMoons;
    float aveParticulateDensity, avePlasmaDensity;
    static float civIndex;

  public:
    LocationData(); //default constructor

    LocationData(string, int, int, float, float); // no default constructor
    void setLocationData(string, int, int, float, float);
    void displaydata();


    static float computeCivIndex(string st, int earth, int moons, float particle, float plasma);

};
```

locationdataimp.cpp

```
float LocationData::civIndex = 0;

//convert sunType to sunTypePercentage
float LocationData::computeCivIndex(string st, int earth, int moons, float particle, float plasma)
{

    float sunTypePercent;

    if(st == "Type 0")
    {
        sunTypePercent = 80.0;
    }
    else if(st == "Type B")
    {
        sunTypePercent = 45.0;
    }
    else if(st == "Type A")
    {
        sunTypePercent = 60.0;
    }
    else if(st == "Type F")
    {
        sunTypePercent = 75.0;
    }
    else if(st == "Type G")
    {
        sunTypePercent = 90.0;
    }
    else if(st == "Type K")
    {
        sunTypePercent = 80.0;
    }
    else if(st == "Type M")
    {
        sunTypePercent = 70.0;
    }

    // calculate CIV Value
    float civNum,civNum1,civNum2,civNum3,civNum4,civNum5;

    civNum1 = sunTypePercent / 100;
    civNum2 = plasma + particle;
    civNum3 = civNum2 / 200;
    civNum4 = civNum1 - civNum3;
    civNum5 = earth + moons;

    civNum = civNum4 * civNum5;

    civIndex = civNum;
    //return civNum;
}
```

pointtwod.h file

```
class PointTwoD
{
private:
    int xcord,ycord;
    float civIndex;
    LocationData locationdata;

public:
        PointTwoD();

        PointTwoD(int, int, string, int, int, float, float, float);

    string toString();

    void displayPointdata();        

};
```

pointtwod.cpp

```
void PointTwoD::displayPointdata()
{
    PointTwoD pointtwod;
    LocationData locationdata;
    cout << "X axis: " << xcord << endl;
    cout << "Y axis: " << ycord << endl;
    cout << "civ: " << locationdata.civIndex  << endl;
    //locationdata.displaydata();
}
```

so what should i include or what mistake have i made?

Comment: Insert a public getter method. Or use `friends`.

Comment: so in my pointtwod.h

float getcivnum;

pointtwod.cpp

float PointTwoD::getcivnum()
{
  return locationdata.civIndex;
}

something like this?

Comment: Why have you commented out the `return civNum` statement? The function is declared to return a float, but it's not returning anything.

Comment: The whole point of making a member variable private is to _prevent_ it from being accessed that way.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration of `static float LocationData::civIndex;` means that `civIndex` is `static` and `private`(*) in `LocationData`.

(*) as the default access modifier

The `private` access means that you cannot access it directly via a variable of type `LocationData` if that class does not explicitly allow it.  You have two options:

1) Provide a public getter function:

```
public static float LocationData::getCivIndex()
{
  return civIndex;
}
```

Note: you will need to declare this function in the class definition as well:

```
class LocationData
{
  // ...
  public static float getCivIndex();
};
```

2) Make the access of `civIndex` in `LocationData` public.

The second option is not advised as that would allow any code to directly access and modify the value of `civIndex`, which can easily lead to errors (and errors of these types are hard to track down in a large project).  Even if you need a setter function that only sets the passed-in value, it is advisable to declare the variable `private` as that forces other code to go through the public method, making it easier to identify what code is accessing the variable during debugging in case of an error.

You can use option 1) like this:

```
LocationData locationData;
locationdata.getCivIndex();
```

Or even without having a variable of type `LocationData`, as the variable is static in that class:

```
LocationData::getCivIndex();
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out being able to just call `LocationData::getCivIndex( );`

Answer (score 1):

`computeCivIndex` is a static member, so the correct syntax is:

```
cout << "civ: " << LocationData::civindex << endl;
```

However, your civindex variable is private, so you have to create a getter:

```
static float getCivIndex()
{
    return civIndex;
}

cout << "civ: " << LocationData::getCivIndex() << endl;
```

Comment: just to check by doing LocationData::Civindex it won't work if I do a cout in pointtwod.cpp right?

Comment: Yes, becuase it's a private member. Private members can only be accesed by the same class.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly access `locationdata.civIndex` like you did. Why? Because you set `civIndex` as a `private` member of the `LocationData` class.

There are a few solutions depending on your needs:

Make `civIndex` a `public` member of `LocationData`

or

Create a getter method to provide `civIndex` such as

```
  static float getCivIndex( )
  {
      return civIndex;
  }
```

See:

[C++ Public](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzk8a7d3.aspx)

[C++ Protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e761de5s.aspx)

[C++ Private](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfbte35d.aspx)

Comment: sorry, if my pointtwod.cpp need to get the civIndex is it possible through this getCivIndex method?

Comment: Yes, you would call `locationdata.getCivIndex( );`